# PHP How to get the "file_put_contents" to work?

Tags: php, file-put-contents

Im very new to programming and this is the first time i use PHP.

Im working on a webpage to switch 433mhz relays and show their current state.
But to know which switch is on or off you need  to remember it when the button is clicked. So i thought of a States.txt file and update a line from 0 to 1. (or from 1 to 0)

I can already read a specific line, but when i try to write on a specific rule using "file_put_contents" it reads the line, and writes to a new file called like the rule.

```
$file = "States.txt";
$lines = file($file);

$btn1 = $lines[0];
$btn2 = $lines[1];
$btn3 = $lines[2];
$btn4 = $lines[3];
$btn5 = $lines[4];
$btn6 = $lines[5];

//file_put_contents($file, "test123");
file_put_contents( $lines[2] , "test123");
```

It should overwrite the specified rule, but instead it reads the line, and creates a new file called like the content of that line.

Comment: And that's what `file_put_contents` does: puts contents into a file.

Comment: Think you need to set the line `$lines[2]  = "test123";` and then `implode()` the lines for the `file_put_contents()` call.

Comment: There's even no need for `implode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = "States.txt";
$lines = file($file);
$lines[2] = 'NEW VALUE' . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
```